# Using tapply() with R-buildin dataset mt cars

Tags: r

Using tapply() with R-buildin dataset mtcars I am trying to use tapply(), to find average mpg for the various transmission type(am) and number of cylinders(cyl)in a car and print it.

I've tried using

```
print(tapply(mtcars$mpg, list(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$am), mean))
```

but i don't get the output in this form:

```
  0      1
1 1.000 2.00000
2 3.000 4.00000
3 5.000 6.00000
```

instead i get

```
    0        1
4 22.900 28.07500
6 19.125 20.56667
8 15.050 15.40000
```

may I know what is the issue here?

Comment: @RonakShah what do u mean, so after i get that output i just reset row names?

Comment: @RonakShah its actually a hackerrank question... i was told to show output in that format but I still can't get it to pass the hidden test cases

Comment: Well, you get the output you are getting, simply because the rownames represent `unique(mtcars$cyl)` i.e. `[1] 6 4 8`. The values are not {1, 2, ..., 6}, because you asked for `mean(mtcars$mpg)` per `cyl` according to transmission type `am`.

Comment: Did you get it then?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you expect the output from `tapply` (as specified in your question) to be

```
  0      1
1 1.000 2.00000
2 3.000 4.00000
3 5.000 6.00000
```

since you are asking for `mean(mtcars$mpg)` per `cyl` according to transmission type `am`. The rownames in the output you got refer to `unique(mtcars$cyl)`. Now if you really would like the output of `tapply` to be as stated above, then you need to make a new column.

```
# function to obtain new values
myfun <- \(DF) {
  new <- with(DF, ifelse(cyl == 4, 1,
                         ifelse(cyl == 6, 3, 5)))
  new <- with(DF, ifelse(am == 0, new,
                          ifelse(am == 1 & cyl == 4, 2*new,
                                 ifelse(am == 1 & cyl == 6, (1+1/3)*new, 1.2*new))))
  return(new)
}
mtcars$new <- myfun(mtcars)

r <- \(x) noquote(format(x, nsmall = 3L))
out <- r(tapply(mtcars$new, list(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$am), mean))
rownames(out) <- c(1,2,3)
```

**Output**

```
> out
  0     1    
1 1.000 2.000
2 3.000 4.000
3 5.000 6.000
```